# On boolean algebras as rings, modules and/or R-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, boolean-algebra

After trying to make sense of first order logic from an algebraic point of view I started to read about boolean algebras (similar to the explanations given here: [wikipedia on boolean algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)). I also read through this post: [Are Elementary Algebra and Boolean Algebra Algebras over a Ring (or Field)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4141/are-elementary-algebra-and-boolean-algebra-algebras-over-a-ring-or-field) (not necessarily all linked pages in full).

As I understand it, taking the initial boolean algebra, call it $B$, as an example, it is an algebra over a ring, or more specifically over the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (which is the underlying set for the whole boolean algebra, so it is an algebra over itself in a sense). The scalar multiplication then coincides with the usual multiplication in $B$. As an $R$-module $M$ becomes an $R$-algebra when $M$ is a ring itself this means that $B$ would be a ring. My questions are these:

Q1.) Is everything I mentioned above correctly understood? If not, would you please explain what I got wrong and/or link to other resources that give a thorough explanation?

Q2.) In the ring of two elements the multiplication table corresponds to the AND operation but the addition corresponds to the XOR operation and not to OR (otherwise $\mathbb{Z}_2$ would obviously not become an additive group). Have I misunderstood something fundamental here or don't we use the OR operation in the initial boolean algebra? And if so, what algebraic structure could this be given?

*My level is undergraduate with an introductory course in abstract algebra covering the most fundamental parts of "Abstract Algebra" by John A. Beachy and William D. Blair, not including Galois theory.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have I misunderstood something fundamental here or don't we use the OR operation in the initial boolean algebra?

Consider the [$\vee$-$\wedge$ definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Monotone_laws) of a Boolean algebra. It turns out that you can turn this into a real [boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring) by defining $a\cdot b=a\wedge b$ and $a+b=(a\vee b)\wedge\neg(a\wedge b)$. As a result, one of the boolean algebra laws says that $a^2=a$ for any $a$ in the algebra.

In the context I've given above, $\vee$ acts like $OR$ and $\wedge$ acts like AND. The "new" addition operation we made acts like XOR. If you want to examine boolean algebras as $F_2$-algebras, then I think you want to shift to the version using the $+$ mentioned above, so that $a+a=0$ for all $a$ in the ring (contrasting with the previous $a\vee a=a$). This is where the characteristic of the field $F_2$ comes into play.

> *it is an algebra over [...] the field $\Bbb Z_2$*

Yes, that's necessary but not sufficient. For example, the ring of polynomials over the field of two elements $F_2[x]$ is an $F_2$ algebra, but $x^2\neq x$.

You can prove using the [technique here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1818479/29335), however, that every boolean algebra $(B, +,\cdot)$ is isomorphic to a subring of $\prod_{i\in I}F_2$ for some index set $I$. This is an $F_2$-algebra, yes, but it is only a small part of the class of $F_2$-algebras.

### Summary

We have seen two fundamental ways to study boolean algebras: using $\vee/\wedge$ or using $+/\cdot$. The first one conforms to more of the way we think with AND and OR, and the second one creates a nice associative ring structure that is easy to analyze. You can freely get between the two with these conversions:

$$a\wedge b=a\cdot b \\
a+b=(a\vee b)\wedge\neg(a\wedge b)\\
a\vee b=a\cdot b+a+b
$$

Comment: I think I'm starting to get a clearer picture. To conclude, do we have any algebraic structure ( preferably among the ones mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure ) that we can put on the boolean algebra defined using OR instead of XOR, i.e using $\vee$ / $\wedge$? Or does this just create something "else" completely?

Comment: @Christopher.L  We've just discussed how $\cdot/+$ makes it into an $F_2$-algebra, and the structure using $\vee/\wedge$ is at least a lattice.